# How create a XLSX file and send it in email apex oracle

Tags: oracle-apex

Need some help please. Actualy i generate a CSV with query, but i need to generate an excel. I have been searching a library or package but i dont see any.

I need some like excel2collection, something that i cound add colors and format to excel and then send it on an email.

Im using oracle apex.

Comment: There are multiple Java packages that can generate XLSX files that can be used with Java stored procedures.  There are PL/SQL packages as well.  Some are going to require licensing.

Comment: In general you can use so called `COM automation` or/and `ODBC` or `OleDB` drivers https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=excel%20odbc%2Foledb   https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=excel%20com%20automation